# Django: Use inline with One to One field

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, one-to-one

I have 3 models User, Student and Teacher.

```
class User(..):
    username=..
    firstname=..
    more_fields..

class Student(..):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, ..)
    a = ..
    more_fields....

class Teacher(..):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, ..)
    b = ..
    more_fields.....
```

At admin side, I want Student and Teacher models to be displayed such that I can fill **fields of User table** when I add new Student/Teacher i.e **Add Student** form should have User model Stacked below it. I'm getting errors while using **inlines** that
***User model does not have foreign key to Student model***

```
**Add Student form**
a <input_field>
more_student_related_fields
username <input_field>
firstname <input_field>
more_user_related_fields
```

Similarly for **Add Teacher form**

Comment: Can you also show *how* you are trying to add the inline model, which is resulting in the said error?

Answer (score -1):

For example, as shown below, if **"Student" and "Teacher" classes** have **"models.OneToOneField()"** referring to **"User" class** which means **"Student" and "Teacher" classes** have **the ForeignKey** referring to **"User" class**:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    name = = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Student(models.Model):
    student_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True
    )

class Teacher(models.Model):
    teacher_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True
    )
```

Then, you can inline **"Student" and "Teacher" classes** under **"User" class** as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User, Student, Teacher

class StudentInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Student

class TeacherInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Teacher

@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (StudentInline, TeacherInline)
```